# Is the Law of Attraction/Law of Assumption permitted to be used (Is it Kishuf if it works or any other issur)?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, sorcery-magic-kishuf

The law of assumption is "a belief that the world does not depend on what is there, but more so the assumptions you form in your mind while looking at it. So your assumptions create your reality. If you assume something will be positive, it will likely go that way. If you assume something is going to be negative, chances are that is how your experience will turn out. In your mind, as you are assuming you are bringing those thoughts to reality."

The law of attraction is "the belief that positive or negative thoughts bring about positive or negative experiences in your life. An example could be that you filled yourself with positive thoughts, and due to that you are attracting positive experiences. The opposite would be filling yourself with negative thoughts which lead to a series of negative experiences."

They are bother very similar.
My question is I have seen many people say this works very well and makes them rich.

Disregarding whether or not that is true, are You allowed to use this in Judaism? Or would it basically be saying that you can get whatever you want without having to ask Hashem? Or could it be kishuf? Or Avodah Zarah? (etc.)

Comment: Might rely on intent. Do you consider it a law of nature? In any case, it's in Jewish Tradition too (whether it's within my own set of beliefs or not), so I think your question is founded on a false premise.

Comment: My own problem with metaphysical causality in general, even those derived from our own sources, is that I don't see why Hashem would introduce more reasons that confound a person getting what is appropriate for them. Physical causality -- I get it. Without rules of physics, we cannot plan ahead. But metaphysical causality other than because of mitzvos or aveiros? It doesn't aid free will nor reward and punishment nor help guide a person to where they need to be. So why?

Comment: It this akin to "The Secret"? That theory states that thoughts and desire can modify reality. A similar idea is indeed found in Torah. If you respond in the affirmative, I will bli neder write you up an answer about it

Comment: Do proponents of these theories claim that they are magical, or are they saying they are laws of nature or human psychology? For example, I could imagine someone saying that if you think positive thoughts you'll be more motivated, people will perceive your attitude, you'll be more perceptive of opportunities, etc. That seems to be an important detail, but I conceded that there can be a fuzzy difference between science and magic if you believe in religion, angels, hashgacha, spiritual forces, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not competent to give a full answer, but the [Maharsha](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Makkot.10b.3?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi) seems to say something similar and define it as within nature:

> בדרך שאדם רוצה ליליך מוליכין אותו כו'. עיין בזה במפרשים ואענה גם אני חלקי דלא קאמר שמוליך אותו הקב"ה אלא מוליכין אותו **והוא ע"פ מה שכתבנו בכמה מקומות שכל מחשבה ודיבור ומעשה האדם הנה הוא בורא לו מלאך לפי ענינו אם לטוב אם לרע וע"כ אמר בדרך שאדם רוצה לילך שהרשות בידי האדם ממנו ית' ב"ה שהכל בידי שמים חוץ מיראת שמים אבל כפי רצונו ודעתו של אדם מוליכין אותו אותן המלאכים הנבראים מאותו רצון ומחשבה אשר בו** ומייתי ראיה מן התורה דכתיב לא תלך עמהם שא"ל הקב"ה כן וכתיב קום לך אתם וגו' שרצונו ודעתו הרעה לילך אתם הביא ששלח לו הקב"ה מלאך כרצונו ומחשבתו שא"ל קום לך אתם ואמר דכתיב אנכי ה' אלהיך מלמדך להועיל וגו' כי כל מצותיו ית' ב"ה אינו מלמדך רק להועיל ולטוב לך אבל מדריכך הוא מלאך שאתה מדריכו בדרך זו תלך כפי דעתך ורצונך ואמר דכתיב אם ללצים הוא יליץ וגו' ר"ל אם ללצים הוא מוסיף לו לץ דהיינו מלאך כפי ליצנותך ואם לענוים הוא יתן חן לעצמו מלאך של חן נגדו ית' ב"ה:

In short, people's thoughts and actions create angels/"spiritual forces" which then lead them in the direction of their thought.